# Translate code from JS to CPP

Tags: javascript, c++, json, hmac

i'm a bit experienced in CPP and totaly new in JS. Have a task in translating code from JS to CPP, i tried something but not clear about what i am doing; hereafter my js code.

```
body: json object

xyz: string (suck as: ALgalgw7agw)

const payload = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(body))
    .toString('base64')

const signature = crypto
  .createHmac('sha384', xyz)
  .update(payload)
  .digest('hex')
```

1) what is the meaning of this code segment?

2) how can i implement it in cpp?

Thanks so much for your time,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: sorry for the dump question, i solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about NodeJS, in this case instances of the Buffer class are similar to arrays of integers but correspond to fixed-sized, raw memory allocations. The size of the Buffer is established when it is created and cannot be resized. After that you are transforming it to a Base64 String.

```
const buf = Buffer.from('hello world', 'ascii');
// Prints: aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=
console.log(buf.toString('base64'));
```

After that you are creating a hash for the payload, using "xyz" variable which is the key to decipher the payload, and then digesting it to a hex. So in the end:

```
signature = /* hex sha384-with-key encrypted payload */
```

If you want to translate this JS code to C++ you'd need to use some kind of crypto library (such as OpenSSL) and for the Buffer I think there are built-in functions.

I suggest you reading [this](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) and [this](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) to know more about crypto and Buffer classes/functions on NodeJS

Comment: thanks @MiGu3x, thank to your help i finished the task.